# Python 3 join list of ints/floats inside print function

Tags: python, list

I would like to join a list of integers inside the print function to cleanly print them out, I am not sure how to do it

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print ('my list contains: ',' '.join(lst))
```

expected output:

```
my list contains: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to ,

```
print ('my list contains: '+' '.join(map(str,lst)))
```

`map(str,lst)` will change  the `lst` to list of strings.The `join` will work only with the list of strings. And it's a single sentence as expected output you have to use `+` instead of `,`.

Executions

```
In [19]: map(str,lst)
Out[19]: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

In [20]: ' '.join(map(str,lst))
Out[20]: '1 2 3 4 5 6'

In [22]: print 'my list contains ',' '.join(map(str,lst))
my list contains  1 2 3 4 5 6

In [23]: print 'my list contains '+' '.join(map(str,lst))
my list contains 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: thank you, can I ask why map() creates a mapping object as opposed to a normal variable? and how best to access the object if I wanted to print it as a flat list? e.g. newlist = map(str,lst)  and then print it as a flat list or perhaps access indexes or search for values

Comment: @new_to_coding As of Python 3.x `map` was changed. Before it did return a list; now you have to cast it to list as `list(map(..., ..))`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes.. I've always preferred "converting" to "casting" as Python terminology, in case our OP has a C background of some sort and gets understandably confused.

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps more pythonic way to do this (instead of using map) is a list comprehension (and the format function):

```
print('my list contains {}'.format(' '.join([str(num) for num in lst])))
```

Comment: There's no need for the list comprehension in there, you might as well just use a generator, e.g. `' '.join(str(num) for num in lst)`

Comment: Makes sense. I just wanted to be safe -- I knew the list comprehension would work, I just wasn't sure that the generator method would work.

Comment: Well it does, and its not wasteful like a list comprehension which you throw away :)

Answer (score 0):

list comprehensions/generators + format is valid for most python-versions:

```
print('my list contains: {}'.format(' '.join(str(i) for i in lst)))
```

for python3.x you can use:

```
print('my list containts: ', end=''); print(*lst)
```